# Need help finding alien anime racing movie

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

So I remember it was on *Adult Swim*, and I remember one ship looked like a starfish kind of shape? It aired like 2007-2009 I believe. It was hosted in another galaxy I think? It wasn't a mainstream movie at all.... It's definitely not redline, or the obu Chan thing. It was a made for TV feeling type of movie. And it was subbed. There was definitely a Japanese feel to it.

Comment: All right, all right, that's a start. Is there anything else you might recall? If so, you can [edit] your question to add those details. Meanwhile, welcome to [fantasy.se]. Have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: No I have not SQB

Comment: Perhaps this list might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Adult_Swim

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier, but all it lists are shows.... Not movies.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Maybe [IGPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_Grand_Prix), but wasn't set on another planet, nor was it a movie.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the race arc of Outlaw Star?

Comment: Adult Swim very rarely shows subbed anime (I want to say never, but it's been a long time since I've watched it). And can you clarify what you mean by "mainstream"? Most of the anime on Adult Swim are mainstream by anime standards. (I want to say all, but again...)

Comment: @machavity, no it wasn't igpx

Comment: @harabeck, no it didn't look like a cartoon.

Comment: @torisuda, when I say non mainstream, I mean like the company it was made by....

Comment: It had more of a redline kind of animation to it

Comment: @DimitriusRios Okay, makes sense. You should edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: The only one I can think of that hasn't been said alread is Oban star racers (the date also fits), but it's not a movie and I don't think it was on [AS]

Answer (score 3):

If it was a racing anime about aliens, but not Red Line, yet similar to Red Line, it has to be...

**Tailenders (2009)**

Close enough to a Star fish:

[image]